# youtube-dl not downloading the whole playlist

Tags: fedora, youtube-dl

Youtube-dl not downloading the whole playlist even though I give the link to a playlist. It downloads and stops after one video. Here are the exact commands I used.

```
youtube-dl --version
2017.05.09

sudo youtube-dl -f bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGwWNGJdvx8&list=PLx0sYbCqOb8TBPRdmBHs5Iftvv9TPboYG
```

I tried with and without sudo

Comment: For me that command (I only tried without `sudo`, you have done something seriously wrong if you ever need to use `sudo` with `youtube-dl`) downloads a lot of files (I interrupted it, because I didn't want to spend discspace on that). Please show us the full output. Maybe try adding `--yes-playlist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are playlist URLs and both will work if you properly [escape special characters or enclose URL in quotes](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#video-url-contains-an-ampersand-and-im-getting-some-strange-output-1-2839-or-v-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command).

```
youtube-dl -f bestaudio 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGwWNGJdvx8&list=PLx0sYbCqOb8TBPRdmBHs5Iftvv9TPboYG'
```

Also, do not use sudo with youtube-dl except for updating using `sudo youtube-dl -U`.